# Mongoose: How can I retrieve an object element stored insider another main object by a field's value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following teamModelSchema schema.

```
var teamMemberModelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "email": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 5,
        "max": 20
    },
    "name": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 5,
        "max": 20
    },
    "role": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 20,
        "max": 50
    },
    "twitter": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 20,
        "max": 50
    },
    "facebook": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 20,
        "max": 50
    },
    "linkedin": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 20,
        "max": 50
    },
});

var teamModelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "title": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 5,
        "max": 20
    },
    "headline": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 5,
        "max": 30
    },
    "description": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 5,
        "max": 80
    },
    "team": [teamMemberModelSchema]
}, { collection: 'team' });
```

I would like to find out an item inside "team" array (an teamMemberModelSchema) that matches a specific email.

I can read it, but I couldn't find a specific item once I have the email address.

How can I do that?

I was trying this way, but an empty result is what that I got.

```
module.exports.getTeamMember = function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.email);
    TeamModel.find({"team": {email:  req.params.email}  }).exec(function(err, team) {
        if (!team) {
            sendJsonResponse(res, 404, {"message": "team member information is not found"});
            return;
        } else if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            sendJsonResponse(res, 404, err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(team);
        sendJsonResponse(res, 200, team);
      });
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select a record from an array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59754692/how-to-select-a-record-from-an-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: it doesn't. it's quite similar but I couldn't update in a way that it worked. Look at the description again to check the approach that I'm trying

Comment: What's not working for you here ? Can you please give a sample doc & required o/p, that way it would be easy..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of changes :

```
module.exports.getTeamMember = function (req, res) {
console.log(req.params.email);
TeamModel.find({ "team.email": 'my@gmail.com' }, { 'team.$': 1, 'title': 1, 'headline': 1, 'description': 1 }).exec(function (err, team) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            sendJsonResponse(res, 404, err); // Does it do res.send() ?
            return; // no need of returns if you do res.send()
        } else if (!team.length) { 
         /** You need above check as you're doing .find() which returns an array you need check it's length, 
             If nothing found it will return [] - so checking length. If you thing there will only be one or none then use .findOne() then you use ur code */
            sendJsonResponse(res, 404, { "message": "team member information is not found" });
            return;
        }
        console.log(team);
        sendJsonResponse(res, 200, team);
    });
};
```

Comment: hello! it worked! thank you! some questions regarding the provided solution. why do I have to put "{ 'team.$': 1, 'title': 1, 'headline': 1, 'description': 1 }" in order to find out the correct record? how to hide _id, title, headline, and description from the result? they come together with the team member found.

Comment: updating...I have left only ".find({ "team.email": req.params.email }, { 'team.$': 1})" on the find method. have a look! it returns only the info that I want and the main id of the document of the collection

Comment: the only question that the remains is the explanation for this. => , {'team.$': 1}. without this, it cannot work. I have to do this = > .find({ "team.email": req.params.email }, {'team.$': 1})

Comment: @OlavoAlexandrino  : For .find({},{}) first one is filter part, Second one is projection, when you do ‘$’ in second part it will return first matching object from team array which matches with the filter passed in..

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the requested info using the .find() method

```js
Team.find({email: "example@email.com"}, (err, foundMember)=>{
  if(err){
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    res.json(foundMember)
  }
})
```

and now that you have foundMember, you can go through it and find any information about that team member